# Load a View from outside the Views folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a widgetmanager for asp.net mvc and to get the main part to work, I need to load in a view from outside the default views folder. I got the following folder structure:

...
- Views
- Widgets
|- Views

I need the views to be loaded from inside ~/Widgets/Views
I'm not sure if I should be writing a Viewengine from scratch or do something else so please feel free to answer :)

p.S. The widgetmanager is called S3WidgetManager and can be found on GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [custom view engine](http://www.leonamarant.com/2011/02/17/adding-a-custom-directory-to-razor-view-engine-partial-view-locations-in-asp-net-mvc3/) and play around with the following base properties which allow you to customize the location of the views:

```
base.ViewLocationFormats
base.PartialViewLocationFormats
base.MasterLocationFormats
base.AreaViewLocationFormats
base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats
base.AreaMasterLocationFormats
```

And here are their default values:

```
base.AreaViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
};
base.AreaMasterLocationFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
};
base.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
};
base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
};
base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
};
base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml", 
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", 
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml" 
};
base.FileExtensions = new string[] 
{ 
    "cshtml", 
    "vbhtml" 
};
```

Comment: When I do that, the Html.RouteLink and the default model variable aren't recognized anymore (probaly more but thats all I use for now). After drag/dropping the file in the default views folder it works fine but ofc I don't want it there

Comment: @MrSoundless, you need to put a web.config file inside your custom folder. The same as the one used in the `~/Views/web.config`. Don't forget that Razor looks for namespaces defined in this file when resolving references in views. Or if you don't want to use such a web.config file you will need to import proper usings in your views in order to bring helpers into scope.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearimg that up, didn't know about that yet!