# Controllers and views in subfolders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, directory-structure

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I would like to organize my controllers and views in the following way:

```
/Controller    
    /Admin
        /LessonController.cs
        /ExerciseController.cs    
    HomeController.cs

/Views
        /Admin
              /Lesson
                   /Index.cshtml
        /Home
              /Index.cshtml
```

I tried the following code to register routes but it does not work:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                url: "Admin/{controller}/action/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Lesson", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

        }
```

Do you have any advices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`areas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), they are kind of designed for this type of segregation and will give you some sort of separation out of the box:

```
/Areas
     /Admin
         /Controllers
             /LessonController.cs
             /ExerciseController.cs    
         /Views
             /Lesson
                 /Index.cshtml
             /Exercise
                 /Index.cshtml
/Controllers    
    /HomeController.cs
/Views
    /Home
        /Index.cshtml
```

If you don't want to follow the standard conventions that are supported by ASP.NET MVC you will have to [`write and register a custom view engine`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184093/29407).

Comment: This article explains using 'areas.'  
http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html

Answer (score 1):

Swap your routes round so the admin one is above the default one, then restart the application.