# MVC Areaname / AreaRegistration: Is using slashes for subfolders acceptable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get a layer deeper than Areas in my new MVC project. It is going to be a fairly large project, and organization is key for me. I would ideally like to use a more nested approach using subdirectories / subfolders, so something like this:

/social/events/admin/edit/1

if i do something like this

```
public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "social/events";
        }
    }
```

everything SEEMS to work like a champ. Resharper, or VS2013 itself, does not like this and shows a red Return View();, however everything compiles and the routing works as expected.

Is there anything "baked-in" that makes this a bad idea? From what I'm seeing, the whole Area convention is litle more than the AreaRegistration.Name mapping to a route. But since we're working with literal strings, well.. we know how this sometimes works.

I'm using MVC5, and although this technically works in this implementation, i'd like to make sure I'm not breaking convention, or if there's a better way to organize this in deeper level than just area/name/controllers. There are going to be a LOT of views, this is a monster of a site.

Comment: I like Darins comment in this one..use Areas!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368427/controllers-and-views-in-subfolders..or create your own view engine..hmm ill get right on that:)

Comment: Is this allowing you to nest areas, or just group similar areas in a top-level folder?

Comment: I saw that thread (I've been looking all over for this), but am already using areas and starting to see limitations to the depth of what can be done "normally". The physical location of this is actually /areas/social/events/.... And yes, creating my own view engine is a pretty unlikely solution. My time would be better spent navigating 300 views in a folder if that's my only option :)

Comment: @TimMedora, the "root" for this is Areas. Where it normally goes Areas/Home/Controllers, It's letting me do Areas/Social/Events/Controllers and Areas/Social/Events/Views/{folder} ... there's a AreaRegistration.cs I'm putting in each "subarea". And seems there has to be a web.config in each of the Views folder

Comment: I see. You can always go through the MVC source, but I'm pretty sure that's not how it was intended to work so it might break in the future. For organization, you *can* add subfolders for views and controllers...just takes a little more work.

Comment: And that's precisely my concern, @TimMedora. I feel like I've "hacked it" to make it work, but am too green at this to know any better. I'll have to look up adding subfolders to views, with areas and how I was doing this before, it seems I get one subfolder in a view folder and no more. 

And, part of this is also growing pains dealing with convention. I'm used to my chaotic "free for all" in my head that'll let me stuff wherever I want. I guess I'm just trying to avoid my project looking like I'm expanding the tree in my StoredProcedures SSMS view.. scrolling through 1,000+ files is boring :D

Comment: one subfolder deep, that is

Comment: I completely understand. When I first began working with MVC (prior to  areas, no less) I couldn't believe how little control I had over the folder structure. I thought I was doing something wrong. I'd suggest building a little test harness and experimenting with subfolders in views. Some cases require a full path (relative to the application root) which may still be better than nothing, but in other cases you can use a fragment like "subfolder/view" which better preserves the convention/separation.

Comment: Last thought: a custom view engine isn't that bad. Usually the piece you customize is just the part that locates views.

Answer (score 0):

Area serves 2 purposes:

It groups routes in logical group when you're doing route lookup, like in `GetVirtualPathForArea` method.

It determines part of the virtual path to views that belong to an area, thus grouping views too. Placeholder `{2}` in paths bellow:

```
AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[]
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
};
```

So as long as your `AreaName` can serve as a key (so any string) and as part of directory path you are fine.